# Combine 2 results of sql join into one result

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am working on an assignment where I need to fetch and display postgres DB data in a following format.

[image]

The query I am trying is,

```
select fv.integer_value as source_id, fv.string_value as source_name, p.amount as amount from payment p 
    INNER join user u on p.user_id = u.id  
        INNER join customer c on u.id = c.user_id
        INNER JOIN customer_field_map cfm ON cfm.customer_id = c.id
        INNER JOIN field_value fv ON cfm.field_value_id = fv.id
        INNER JOIN field_name fn ON fn.id = fv.field_name_id
        WHERE fn.name in ('source_id', 'source_name')
    group by source_id, source_name, amount;
```

The field_value table structure is like,

```
field_value (
    id,
    field_name_id,
    integer_value,
    String_value
)
```

Consider the following user record spread across `user`, `field_name` and `field_value` etc tables,

```
user_id  source_id   source_name   amount
10        100         source-1      100
```

For above record the sql query above gives me 2 results like,

[image]

Any suggestions how can I achieve the desired result and combine 2 results into one as shown in image at the beginning.

The source_id and source_name combination will not vary but multiple users can have the same combination.

**EDIT**

The detailed table structures and sample data is on following lines,

```
user (
id integer,
user_name character varying (100)
)

id    name
------------------------
100  test-name

customer (
id integer,
user_id integer
)

id      user_id
------------------------
100     100

payment (
 id integer,
 user_id integer,
 amount numeric
)

id      user_id   amount
------------------------
100     100       100


field_name (
 id integer,
 name character varying (100)
)

id      name
------------------------
100     source_id
101     source_name

field_value (
    id,
    field_name_id,
    integer_value,
    String_value
)

id      name     integer_value     string_value   
----------------------------------------------------
100     100       101             null  
101     101       null            source-1


customer_field_map (
   customer_id integer,
   field_value_id integer  
)

customer_id     field_value_id
----------------------------------------------------
100              100
100              101
```

Comment: Please show us the table data. Please insert it as copyable text not as an image into the question!

Comment: @S-Man Added some details about table structures and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a little hard to follow because your query returns three columns but the data has four.

If you want one row per user, then the `group by` should contain only one key -- `u.id`.  So:

```
select u.id, max(fv.integer_value) as source_id,
       max(fv.string_value) as source_name, p.amount as amount
from payment p join
     user u
     on p.user_id = u.id join
     customer c 
     on u.id = c.user_id join
     customer_field_map cfm 
     on cfm.customer_id = c.id join
     field_value fv 
     on cfm.field_value_id = fv.id join
     field_name fn ON fn.id = fv.field_name_id 
where fn.name in ('source_id', 'source_name')
group by u.id;
```

Comment: The source_id, source_name combination can be duplicated across users. Meaning multiple users can have same values of source_id, source_name. In that case, with your suggested query the results are grouped by user ids and I get multiple results for same combination of source_id, source_name. I would like to get sum of payments for unique combinations of source_id, source_name.